# How to specify contents of {{{1}}} to avoid wiki markup

Tags: mediawiki

I have a template that, amongst other things, contains this:

```
<nowiki>{{{1}}}</nowiki>
```

Now, I knew when I wrote this that it wouldn't work, but it represents what I'm trying to do. The contents of `{{{1}}}` should not parse wiki markup, but this of course results in `{{{1}}}` not being parsed.

How can I achieve this?

Update:
I found the answer on wikipedia, but I'm having a hard time implementing it. I've copied the Dtag and Nowiki meta templates from Wikipedia. I can't figure out how to make them work though. I'm using:

```
{{<includeonly>subst:</includeonly>Nowiki|{{{1}}}}}</nowiki>
```

And it results in this output:

```
{{subst:dtag|nowiki|{{{1}}}}}</nowiki>
```

Comment: Why do people keep editing my question to remove my thanks? Is it so wrong to say thank you?

Comment: In regards to saying thanks: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/229309

Comment: That post just so happens to be riddled with people complaining that a single line thanks should not be removed. Police the intent. Don't remove everything. I did not ramble, I did not make my post harder to read by extraneous text. I simply gave a one-line thanks. To do otherwise would be rude. I am trying to express that I really appreciate what the community here does, without making it harder for them to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 1.12, there is a magic word for arbitrary tag insertion: `{{#tag:nowiki|{{{1}}}}}`.  See [documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aMagic_words#Miscellaneous).